# How to migrate from an array of strings to a single integer value (JSONB)

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, jsonb

I have a table "documents" with a jsonb column "metadata" which I need to migrate to a different structure.
How can I turn this:
`{"BirthYear": ["1999"]}`
into this:
`{"birthYear":1999}`

Notice that 1999 is now integer, no longer String.

What I tried so far:
`update documents set metadata = jsonb_set(metadata #-'{BirthYear}', '{birthYear}', metadata -> 'BirthYear' -> 0)`
But this code only moves the String value from one place to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value as text, cast to integer and convert to jsonb:

```sql
update documents 
set metadata = jsonb_set(
    metadata #-'{BirthYear}', 
    '{birthYear}', 
    to_jsonb((metadata -> 'BirthYear' ->> 0)::int))
```